# QuadrilateralTransformation Class

Tags: c#, aforge

i tray QuadrilateralTransformation Class to convert the image to rectangle, the image has been rectangle, but i want to know the new coordinates of any point so i want the transformation array can you help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in the sourcecode of the class:

https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Imaging/Filters/Transform/QuadrilateralTransformation.cs

there is no function which allowes that. but as aforge is open source, you can copy the part which calculates the new rectangle, so the function `QuadTransformationCalcs.MapQuadToQuad` and calculate with the returning matrix the new point. 
all the code you need is in the upper source code file

Comment: Thank you very much, i was trying this solutions but i couldnot know the source code, thank you.